# RDO Openstack, Ceilometer, Heat autoscaling instance

Tags: openstack, autoscaling, openstack-heat, ceilometer, rdo

Below is the code and instructions which I use to scale the instances on the RDO. Can anyone tell me why new instances are not created. What could be the reason and where I can see why it is not working ?
The alarm is created but instances did not create.

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------+------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
| Alarm ID                             | Name                               | State | Severity | Enabled | Continuous | Alarm condition               | Time constraints |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------+------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
| 50d52c2f-fdaf-4767-818d-3cfd91c1848a | simple-cpu_alarm_high-26y5dsoucoub | alarm | low      | True    | True       | cpu_util > 0.1 during 1 x 60s | None             |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------+------------+-------------------------------+------------------+
```

I wait more then 10 min (default interval time) but the new instance is not created

I did all steps from this side [Simple auto scaling environment with Heat](http://superuser.openstack.org/articles/simple-auto-scaling-environment-with-heat)
and I have Stack with two instances. I waited even 30 min and nothing. I load manually these instances CPU to 70 % but nothing change. Any Ideas ?

Comment: What does your Heat template look like? Have you tried manually triggering the autoscaling action?  Is your heat-api-cfn service running?

Comment: @larsks, thank for your answer, the issue why it was not working, was not running   heat-api-cfn service